# Use Comma as decimal separator for android EditText with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing an application for Android using Xamarin with MvvmCross.
I have an `EditText` defined this way:

```
<EditText
            local:MvxBind="Text PorcentagemDesconto"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/valorDesconto"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="%"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

When I click on the `EditText`, the keyboard don't gives me the option to insert a **Comma**, only a **Dot** to use as decimal separator. The problem here is that when I insert the number **2.22** for example, the Binding assumes that the value is **222**, because my device is using the **pt-BR** locale, that uses commas for decimals and dots for thousands.

I already did the following to solve the problem:

Created a `ValueConverter` that replaces the **dot** for the **comma**

```
public class DecimalValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strValue = value?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
            return null;

        strValue = strValue.Replace(".", ",");

        return strValue;
    }
}
```

but this way, as soon as the user enters the first decimal digit, the cursor moves to the start of the `EditText`, so, I also used the `TextChanged` event of the `EditText` to set the selection on the end of the input to solve that.

```
var porcentagemDesconto = v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.porcentagemDesconto);
porcentagemDesconto.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        if (porcentagemDesconto.Text != null)
        {
            porcentagemDesconto.SetSelection(porcentagemDesconto.Text.Length);
        }
    });
};
```

But to be honest, I did not like this solution. I would need to either write the event code for ALL my `EditTexts` that accespt decimals, or create a custom view that does that.

I find very hard to belive that I would need to create a **custom view** and a `ValueConverter` just to use a comma as a decimal separator, so, I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

I've also already tried to use the `android:digits="0123456789,-"`, but this way the comma don't appear on the keyboard, only the dot. The only difference is that this way, when I click the dot, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626) that is unfixed since 2009.

You have to set `android:digits`.

```
<EditText
    local:MvxBind="Text PorcentagemDesconto"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="%"
    android:digits="0123456789,-"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

If you want to deploy your app for different countries, you have to use a string resource `android:digits="@string/localized_digits` with

**values-de/strings.xml** e.g. german

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="localized_digits">0123456789,-</string>
</resources>
```

**values/strings.xml** default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="localized_digits">0123456789.-</string>
</resources>
```

**Or** use a more generic approach and set it via code:

```
// extension method
public static class EditTextExtension
{
    public static void FixDigits(this EditText text)
    {
        var decimalSign = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        var digits = $"0123456789{decimalSign}-";
        text.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(digits);
    }
}

// usage
FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtNumber).FixDigits();
```

**Or** you add thr functionality of the extension method `FixDigits()` to your custom EditText class.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for the answer. I tried the **android:digits** solution. Please check my edit. There's some way to show the comma on the keyboard?

Comment: Hmm my keyboard shows the comma. Have you got the default keyboard or custom one? which android version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default keyboard and my device is a Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0.

Comment: Using the DigitsKeyListener worked. When used, the keyboard shows an option with the **".,-+"** text. Clicking it the first time it shows a dot, the second shows the comma and so on. I found very strange that the android:digits solution did not work though.

Comment: @PedroMartinsTimóteodaCosta Was the code working in Samsung devices ?